# Составить регулярку для парсинга ссылок вида: /path/to/dir

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Помогите составить регулярку, если это возможно, для получения

```
product
basket
catalog
leading
payment
basketsuccess
signregistration
```

Из этих ссылок:

```
/nl/product/prod-1233
/nl/basket/basket
/nl/catalog/all
/catalog/all
/leading/led-123131
/fr/leading/led-3413
/fr/payment/payment
/fr/basketsuccess/basketsuccess
/signregistration/
```

1 ссылка - 1 параметр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
r'(\/[a-z][a-z]\/)?([a-z]+)\/'
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Ещё решение https://regex101.com/r/SQFEx3/2/

Comment: @RomanKravets А для `/catalog/all` - это разве сработает?

Answer (score 0):

Строки у вас являются POSIX путями, поэтому [можно `pathlib` использовать, чтобы достать нужную часть](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import PurePosixPath as Path

for path in map(Path, lines):
    print(path.parts[2] if path.parts[1] in {'nl', 'fr'} else path.parts[1])
```